# How can I rasterize expressions with Runic characters in Wolfram Cloud?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, mathematica-online, character-encoding, rasterize, unicode

Here is my function to create polynomials with a specific format:

```
distinguishedCoefficientPolynomial[degree_] := Module[{polynomial = 0},
  ClearAttributes[Times, Orderless];
  ClearAttributes[Plus, Orderless];

  Do[
    polynomial += Times[Subsuperscript[ᛈ, i, degree], x^i],
    {i, degree, 0, -1}
  ];
  polynomial
]
```

And it works exactly as expected for any positive integer when I do something like:

```
distinguishedCoefficientPolynomial[1]
```

or

```
distinguishedCoefficientPolynomial[2]
```

but `Rasterize[distinguishedCoefficientPolynomial[1]]` gives

[image: Rasterized image of linear polynomial.]

and `Rasterize[distinguishedCoefficientPolynomial[2]]` gives:

[image: Rasterized image of quadratic polynomial.]...

**UPDATE**
Here is a photo that include the function, what it should look like, then followed by when I try to rasterize it. I am using Mathematica Online.

[image: This is a photo of the notebook.]

Comment: Works as expected with version 13 or version 14. What version are you using?

Comment: @BobHanlon I am using Mathematica Online because I have a Chromebook.

Comment: The cloud probably doesn't have that font available locally to render your content with.

Comment: @ihojnicki It works for the mathematical expressions in the Notebook, it just doesn't rasterize. So I am not sure your comment applies. I gave a photo of the notebook screenshot. If I am wrong, how would I fix it?

Comment: There is indeed something weird. For example, it doesn't work for any of the fonts: `Rasterize[Style[distinguishedCoefficientPolynomial[1], FontFamily ->#],ImageSize->300]&/@$FontFamilies`. Also, it is interesting to observe other characters: `Rasterize[StringJoin[Table[FromCharacterCode[i], 5832-100,5832+50}]], ImageSize->2000]`. Almost all of them are fine on [desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNl6H.png), but only a few of them in [Cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKDrY.png).

Comment: @TegLouis, I have slightly edited your question to emphasize the fact that the problem is in the Cloud (online) version of Mathematica, because the desktop one seems to work fine.

Comment: @Domen Good call. Thanks.

Comment: @TegLouis, the rasterized version has to happen locally on the server.  The non-rasterized version is rendered by your web browser.  One side has the font, the other doesn't.

Comment: @ihojnicki How would I fix that to add locally on the server?

Comment: @TegLouis, you should ask support.  I would not be surprised if it was not allowed though.

Comment: @ihojnicki Thank you! Understandable. I will try fairly soon.